# NodeJS - How to remove the first line of a text file without read all lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, readfile

I have the following file in the S3 bucket:

```
field1;field2;field3
VAL11,VAL12;VAL13
VAL21,VAL22;VAL23
VAL31,VAL32;VAL33
```

The final goal is to remove only the first line of the file `field1;field2;field3`. This is the desired result:

```
VAL11,VAL12;VAL13
VAL21,VAL22;VAL23
VAL31,VAL32;VAL33
```

For the moment I have the following function that is reading all the content form the file. And breaking down using `\n`, removing the first line and then concatenating all again using `\n`.

So is there a way to remove this first line without breaking down and assembling again?

```
async function createRef (version,FIRMWARE_BUCKET_NAME) {
    const refFile = version + '/ref.ref'
    const ref = await getObject(FIRMWARE_BUCKET_NAME, refFile)
    const refString = ref.toString('utf8')
    let arrRef = refString.split('\n')
    arrRef.shift()
    
    let refConcatenated=''
    for (let i = 0; i < arrRef.length; i++) {
        if (arrRef[i] !== '' ) {
            let line = arrRef[i]
            refConcatenated = refConcatenated + line + '\n'
        }
    }
    return refConcatenated
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [not possible](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2044) to remove one line without re-reading and writing the whole file in some way — you can *replace* lines as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873428/5774952), or use streaming to avoid needing to read the whole file into memory as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365494/5774952). If you wanted to truncate the file you could use [fs.truncate](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_ftruncate_fd_len_callback), but that won't help you for removing the *first* line. You can at least probably simplify last part of your function by using `.join('\n')` rather than looping.